# Package CJKutf8 causes problems with text formatting

Tags: formatting, unicode, japanese

I'd like to add only one quote in Japanese in my document.
My document looked perfect, but when I added

```
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
```

at the beginning and

```
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}水が綺麗になら虹も一杯\end{CJK}
```

where I wanted the quote, all my subsubsection titles lost their boldness, as the titles of my item lists. What did I do wrong? Here are the packages I use, if it's useful:

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}


% BIBLIOGRAPHIE

\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp,autolang=hyphen]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{essai.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citehyperref}
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \bibhyperref{\usebibmacro{title}\printtext[parens]{\printfield{year}}}}    
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,book,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{title}{\printnames{author}\addcolon\space\textit{#1}\isdot}

% FIN BIBLIOGRAPHIE

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{epigraph} % citation retenue

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{datetime}
\newdate{datexxx}{01}{09}{2023}
\date{\displaydate{datexxx}}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newenvironment{dialogue}{\parskip=0pt\relax\obeylines}\smallskip

\usepackage{uarial}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}
\setlength{\headheight}{35pt}

\usepackage{titling}

\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
  \posttitle{%
    \par\end{center}
    \begin{center}\large#1\end{center}
    \vskip0.5em}%
}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\title{XXX}
\subtitle{XXX}
\author{XXX}

\usepackage{hyperref,xcolor}
\definecolor{winered}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{gris}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.2}
\definecolor{bleuclair}{RGB}{207,231,226}
\definecolor{vert}{RGB}{132,246,132}

\hypersetup
{
pdfauthor={César},
pdfsubject={XXX},
pdftitle={XXX},
pdfkeywords={xxx, yyy, zzz},
% colorlinks=false,
pdfborder={0 0 0},
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor={gris},
urlcolor={winered},
filecolor={winered},
citecolor={winered}
}

% --- Glossaire et acronymes
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{xxx}{XXX}{XXX XX}

\frenchbsetup{StandardLists=true} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
```

Comment: don't show snippets, always create a small but complete document that demonstrates your issue so that one test it.

Answer (score 1):

I think using a method like the following is much more simple and modern. Note that you need to use LuaLaTeX (recommended) or XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\jptxt{HaranoAjiMincho}
\title{English and {\jptxt 日本語}}
\author{Me or {\jptxt 私}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[1-1]
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents

\section{Hello world}
\lipsum[1-1]
\section{{\jptxt 水が綺麗になら虹も一杯}}
\lipsum[1-1]
\end{document}
```

This loads a Unicode font which is distributed with LaTeX-distributions.

Comment: Using LuaLatex is for the moment not an option as I've just tried and the amount of errors I have seems too high for me to solve them completely... I upvoted your answer, though, as it might be useful for next projects.

Comment: @djcaesar9114 It would be a strange situation if your code works with PDFLaTeX and doesn't work with LuaLaTeX. Typically this shouldn't happen, but anyways, I can help you debug.

Comment: Also, there are cases where a code working in XeLaTeX fails with LuaLaTeX and if you are using XeLaTeX, let me mention that my method should work with XeLaTeX too.