# Missing character: There is no 蒋 (U+848B) in font [lmsans17-regular]:mapping=tex-text;!

Tags: cjk

When I render this document in macOS 13.2:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\setlength{\footskip}{149.60005pt}
\name{蒋}{小强}
\phone[mobile]{15682721628}
\email{jianng@gmail.com}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}
\makecvtitle
\section{Education}

\cventry{2023.05--2023.05}{本科}{中国药科大学}{}{}{}

\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

the output log info shows that:

```
11628 bytes written
Latexmk: Summary of warnings from last run of *latex:
  =====Latex reported missing or unavailable character(s).
=====See log file for details.
Latexmk: ====List of undefined refs and citations:
  Missing character: There is no 蒋 (U+848B) in font [lmsans17-regular]:mapping=tex-text;!
  Missing character: There is no 小 (U+5C0F) in font [lmsans17-regular]:mapping=tex-text;!
  Missing character: There is no 强 (U+5F3A) in font [lmsans17-regular]:mapping=tex-text;!
  Missing character: There is no 本 (U+672C) in font [lmsans10-bold]:mapping=tex-text;!
  Missing character: There is no 科 (U+79D1) in font [lmsans10-bold]:mapping=tex-text;!
  Missing character: There is no 中 (U+4E2D) in font [lmsans10-oblique]:mapping=tex-text;!
  Missing character: There is no 国 (U+56FD) in font [lmsans10-oblique]:mapping=tex-text;!
 And 4 more --- see log file.
Latexmk: All targets (modern.pdf) are up-to-date
Latexmk: I have not found a previewer that is already running. 
   So I will start it for 'modern.pdf'
```

and the pdf did not output Chinese words. Am I missing something? What should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Since you are using Unicode, can you try following [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/684065/174620) method? It is a modern way of typesetting Unicode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ctex` or `xeCJK` package.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\usepackage[scheme=plain]{ctex}
% or
% \usepackage{xeCJK}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% \usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\setlength{\footskip}{149.60005pt}
\name{蒋}{小强}
\phone[mobile]{15682721628}
\email{jianng@gmail.com}
\begin{document}
% \begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}
\makecvtitle
\section{Education}

\cventry{2023.05--2023.05}{本科}{中国药科大学}{}{}{}

% \end{CJK}
\end{document}
```